# Pushing Multiple values into array gives error using angular6

Tags: angular6

I am working in angular 6 here i want to push multiple values into array which gives me the following error

[image]

here is my code

```
 this._model.NomineeList.push(
          {
              'FirstName': this._nomineemodel.FirstName,
              'CNIC': this._nomineemodel.CNIC,
              'MiddleName': this._nomineemodel.MiddleName,
              'LandlineNumber': this._nomineemodel.LandlineNumber,
              'LastName': this._nomineemodel.LastName,
              'MobileNumber': this._nomineemodel.MobileNumber,
              'PermanentAddress': this._nomineemodel.PermanentAddress,
              'PresentAddress': this._nomineemodel.PresentAddress,
              'RelationId': this._nomineemodel.RelationId,
              'RelationName': this._nomineemodel.RelationName,
              'UPermanentAddress': '',
              'UPresentAddress': ''
          });
```

How to push into array using angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, the kind on model you are inserting in your array they are not identical. there are two possible reasons.

1) Either you haven't initiated the array with empty values. or

2) The model you are inserting is missing mandatory properties or the new model having few extra properties or spell mistake in properly name.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53894260?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) example.

Comment: I have initiated the array and also this._nomineeList and this.nomineemodel are same classes i am using. I don't why it is giving the error

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code on stackbliz to understand your issue further.